# TF dataset sample_from_datasets is not working when used iteratively, is this a bug in tf ds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a dataset with each class having sub folders. I want to balance all the way from sub folders to main classes. I created a dataset for each subfolder and created balanced dataset for each class using sample_from_datasets. Then I created balanced dataset using above balanced class datasets to form final balanced dataset. But its not working as expected.

```
    """method to create a subdirectory balanced dataset"""
import os
import random
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_class_dir_dict(root_directory, classes):
    class_dir_dict = {}
    folder_paths = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_directory):
        if not dirnames:  # Only collect the folder paths without subdirectories
            folder_paths.append(dirpath)
            for class_name in classes:
                if class_name in dirpath.split(os.sep):
                    if class_dir_dict.get(class_name) is None:
                        class_dir_dict[class_name] = [dirpath]
                    else:
                        class_dir_dict[class_name].append(dirpath)
    for class_dir_dict_key in class_dir_dict.keys():
        print(class_dir_dict_key, len(class_dir_dict[class_dir_dict_key]))
    return class_dir_dict


def process_path(file_path, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 224])
    img = img / 255.0
    return img, label


def create_dataset_from_folder(filenames, labels):
    filename_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    label_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((filename_dataset, label_dataset))

    dataset = dataset.map(process_path)

    return dataset


def get_balanced_dataset(root_directory, classes, min_count=100, undersample=False):
    class_dir_dict = get_class_dir_dict(root_directory, classes)
    # create dataset of each subdirectory
    main_dataset = []
    for class_dir_dict_key in class_dir_dict.keys():
        print("\n", class_dir_dict_key)
        one_class_datasets = []
        for dirpath in class_dir_dict[class_dir_dict_key]:
            print(dirpath)
            filenames = os.listdir(dirpath)
            img_names = []
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
                    filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    img_names.append(filename)
            print(len(img_names))
            # create tf dataset of filenames and labels
            label = classes.index(class_dir_dict_key)
            labels = [label] * len(img_names)
            ds = create_dataset_from_folder(img_names, labels)
            if len(img_names) < min_count:
                ds = ds.repeat()
            if undersample:
                ds = ds.shuffle(min_count)
                ds = ds.take(min_count)
            one_class_datasets.append(ds)
        sample_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(
            one_class_datasets,
            weights=[1 / len(one_class_datasets)] * len(one_class_datasets),
        )
        main_dataset.append(sample_dataset)
    final_ds = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(
        main_dataset, weights=[1 / len(main_dataset)] * len(main_dataset)
    )
    return final_ds


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your dataset root directory
    root_directory = "DB"

    # Choose your classes!
    classes = ["male", "female"]
    # classes = ["kid", "middle", "old"]

    final_ds = get_balanced_dataset(
        root_directory, classes, min_count=10, undersample=True
    )

    # Test the dataset by displaying the first image and label
    print(final_ds.element_spec)
    counts = {class_name: 0 for class_name in classes}
    for image, label in final_ds.take(30):
        # cv2 imshow
        image = image.numpy()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        print(label.numpy())
        cv2.waitKey(300)
        counts[classes[label.numpy()]] += 1
    print(counts)
```

Results in

```
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```